# How do I set the width of the second box the same as the width of two boxes in the first row?

Tags: html, responsive-design, media-queries, css-float, css-position

I have designed a page so that it can respond to different devices. So for large devices, there are three columns and for medium devices there are 2 columns and two rows.

The first row has two columns and the second row has one column.

How can I make the second row column span the same width as the two columns in the first row?

https://tawnyrich.github.io/Cousera-Course/module2-assignment/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the classes of the third column (the one with the beef text) to

```
col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12
```

You can probably see what this will do, but let me know if you need more explanation.